# Filter the cxLookUpCombobox for certain values

Tags: delphi, devexpress

My cxlookupcombobox gets its data from a table called PRICE_LIST (database is SQLite).

One of the fields in that table is called FOR_SALE and is a boolean field.

How can I filter the cxlookupcombobox so it only shows the items that are checked (I think sqlite uses '1' for 'true') in the table?

I do not wish to filter the table just the cxlookupcombobox so it shows me only the items that are checked in the grid.

Comment: How you searched the [DevEx support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/List/1)?

Comment: I could not find such a scenario.